# AD query by email address from csv output of disabled and expired

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I manage Adobe CC licenses. From their enterprise portal only email addresses of licensed users can be exported. I need to take that csv list of email addresses and query AD for disabled and expired accounts to minimize costs. There are over 1000 end users with licenses and manual searches are too time consuming.

I'll be the first to admit I am not a developer. Just looking for a nice script and cannot find one to fit my needs from internet searches.

Hoping to have an export of results to show email address, if account is disabled and or expired.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. SO is a community of developers helping developers. A developer can range from just learning to being a expert. So if you are wanting to learn how to code then I would suggest that you try making this script yourself and then ask question around the things you are struggling to learn. Show code that you have made and ask direct questions about the issue with the code. If you are looking for someone to just write a script for you that is why you hire a developer. What you are looking to accomplish in your post is very easy and can be done in one line of code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is asking someone to write code for them

Comment: Understood, but Brutal for one line of code.

Comment: No no its very simple. You just need to search AD. Powershell already has commands for that. Get-ADUSer and you can filter out disabled or locked accounts. But i am more willing to help you if you try

Comment: I guess thanks for forcing me to figure out, I'm good. Here it is for anyone else needing it on an internet search:

Comment: Get-Content c:\users.csv |
 ForEach-Object{
  Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$_'" -Properties EmailAddress, SAMAccountName,AccountExpirationDate,Enabled
 } |
 Select EmailAddress, SAMAccountName,AccountExpirationDate,Enabled |
 Export-CSV .\allinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: I suggest you submit your own answer to your question. No one will see it in comments. Also great job :) looks like a single line of code to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as Gthomas5634 posted this as his solution. I didnt want it to get lost in the comments as another unanswered question.

```
Get-Content c:\users.csv | %{ 
    Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$_'" -Properties EmailAddress, 
    SAMAccountName,AccountExpirationDate,Enabled 
} | Select EmailAddress, SAMAccountName,AccountExpirationDate,Enabled | Export-CSV .\allinfo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```